# How to solve this kind of nonlinear differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve the following equation

$$ z'-e^z=2$$

where $z=f(x)$, but I can't solve this. Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try multiplying by $\mathrm{e}^{-z}$, as this will lead to 
$$
\mathrm{e}^{-z}z’ - 1 = 2\mathrm{e}^{-z}
$$
Or
$$
-(\mathrm{e}^{-z})’ - 1 = 2\mathrm{e}^{-z}
$$
We can then re-write as
$$
-y’ -1 = 2y
$$
With $y=\mathrm{e}^{-z}$. Should be easier to solve.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like Bernouilli 's equation
$$z'=e^z+2$$
substitute 
$$u=e^z+2 \implies \frac {du}{dz}=e^z=u-2$$
The equation becomes
$$\frac {dz}{dt}=u$$
$$\frac {dz}{du}\frac {du}{dt}=u$$
$$\frac {du}{dt}=u\frac {du}{dz}$$
$$\frac {du}{dt}=u(u-2)$$
$$u'_t+2u=u^2$$
This last one is Bernouilli's equation. But it's also separable. And easier to integrate that way
$$\int \frac {du}{u(u-2)}=\int dt$$